# Google oAuth redirect hanging NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Currently creating app that utlises google oAuth-20, during the redirect back to my website the process hangs eventually giving me a code was redeemed, presumly activated by a time out error because the instance of google logs you in.
I'm going to assume there's a problem with the following promise

```
let passport = require('passport'),
    GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy,
    keys = require('./keys')
    User = require('../models/user-model');


passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
});

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        // options for google strategy
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect'
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // check if user already exists in our own db
        User.findOne({googleId: profile.id}).then((currentUser) => {
            if(currentUser){
                // already have this user
                console.log('user is: ', currentUser);
                done(null, currentUser);
            } else {
                // if not, create user in our db
                new User({
                    googleId: profile.id,
                    username: profile.displayName,
                }).save().then((newUser) => {
                    console.log('created new user: ', newUser);
                    done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    })
);
```

I believe the error is during this code block -

```
}).save().then((newUser) => {
                        console.log('created new user: ', newUser);
                        done(null, newUser);
                    });
```

as the user details requested from google are printed to the screen, how ever I am getting a 'nhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function wit                          hout a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)'

Passport is init' in my sever.js file -

```
let express = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passportConfig = require('./config/passport-config'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    keys = require('./config/keys'),
    cookieSession = require('cookie-session'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    User = require('./models/user-model'),
app = express();


//Define routes for configuration - refactor into dedicated file
let landingRoute = require('./routes/landingpage'),
    authenticationRoute = require('./routes/authentication'),
    profileRoute = require('./routes/profile');

app.use(landingRoute);
app.use('/profile', profileRoute);
app.use('/auth', authenticationRoute);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cookieSession({
    //sets the max age of the cookie to 1 day
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [
        keys.sessionKey.cookieKey
    ]
}));


// initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//mongodb connection configuration 
mongoose.connect(keys.mongodb.dbURI, () => {
    console.log('db connected');
});

//General app configuration
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));


let port = 8080

//Listen ports
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Sever started");
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: printed to the console***

Comment: Did you try adding chaining catch to the end of your promises to get a better idea what the error is?

Comment: @Michaelabbott, are you using MongoDB database?